# Using If and Vlookup in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, join

This is what my query output looks like and i have modified the data for easier viewing.

```
TABLE A
                +--+--------------+----------------+----------------+
                |ID|Item Name     | Num of Sales   | Current Stock  |
                +-----------------+----------------+----------------+
                |67| Yellow Table |              23| 0              |
                |68| Red Glass    |              55| 0              |
                |69| Blue Chair   |              54| 0              |
                |70| Black stool  |              66| 0              |
                +--+--------------+----------------+----------------+
```

However "Current Stock" for "Red Glass" in another table is duplicated because it has actually 2 kind of merchant that provide the stock item in "Table B". This is the output query for the "Table B"

```
Table B
        +----+--------------+--------------+----------------+
        | Id | Item Name    | Current Stock| Merchant       |
        +----+--------------+--------------+----------------+
        |  68| Red Glass    |             0|Merchant A      |
        |  68| Red Glass    |           700|Merchant B      |
        +----+--------------+--------------+----------------+
```

What I am trying to result is like this, where the filter is `"Current stock" = 0`. Because `Red Glass` is actually not zero due to having stock in Merchant B.

```
                +--+--------------+----------------+----------------+
                |ID|Item Name     | Num of Sales   | Current Stock  |
                +-----------------+----------------+----------------+
                |67| Yellow Table |              23| 0              |
                |69| Blue Chair   |              54| 0              |
                |70| Black stool  |              66| 0              |
                +--+--------------+----------------+----------------+
```

Where item similar like "Red Glass" that have more than 1 Merchant in "Table B" should not detected having 0 current stock. I was thinking about doing similar Vlookup in excel to sum the "Current Stock" in Table B. Or using `Case When` to detect the duplicate row and then sum the "Current Stock" column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be easy with a `NOT EXISTS` subquery. Assuming the tables are as you show them:

```
selact a.*
from a
where "Current Stock" = 0
  and not exists
      ( select * 
        from b 
        where b.id = a.id
          and "Current Stock" > 0
      ) ;
```